# dlopen with RTLD_NOW results a crash

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

Situation: I use python ctypes module to load a c shared lib which in fact ctypes module use dlopen with RTLD_NOW to load the shared lib. When I use the shared lib, it crashed when called a very strange function address.

core stack like follows:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  **0x00000000001723f6** in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f39a9d1b506 in do_io ()
   from /home/z/libgshared.so
#2  0x00007f39b84dddf5 in start_thread (arg=0x7f39a9101700)
   at pthread_create.c:308
#3  0x00007f39b7b021ad in clone ()
   at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:113
```

then I went deeper and find the strange address is from **GOT**, which means the dlopen not calculate the actual addresses in some of functions.

```
(gdb) disas 0x7f39a9ba63f0
Dump of assembler code for function zookeeper_process@plt:
   0x00007f39a9ba63f0 <+0>: jmpq   *0x42d452(%rip)        # 0x7f39a9fd3848
   0x00007f39a9ba63f6 <+6>: pushq  $0xf06
   0x00007f39a9ba63fb <+11>:    jmpq   0x7f39a9b97380
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/2a 0x7f39a9fd3848
0x7f39a9fd3848: **0x1723f6**    0x172406
(gdb)
```

see the address **0x1723f6** is exact the cored address in frame 0.

I wonder why this is happened, and How can I work around it or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> 0x7f39a9fd3848: 0x1723f6    0x172406

These are *unrelocated* `GOT` entries inside whatever library contains `0x7f39a9ba63f0` (and `0x7f39a9fd3848`), probably `libgshared.so`.

You are possibly running into this GLIBC [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/919202).

Comment: Thank u for  applying the infomation. I check the glibc version on my centos7 vm, the version of glibc is 2.17, which contains the fix of that bug. Is there any other possibilities that may result this result? What about shared lib dependency?